# пирамида из чисел на java

Tags: java

нужно построить такую пирамиду для любого введенного числа,заранее спасибо [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуй для начала самому сделать

Answer (score 4):

Алгоритм такой:

1. Добавим цикл на `n*2-1` итераций, т.к. каждая строка повторяется дважды, кроме той, где есть все `n` цифр.
2. Дальше создаем (или в нашем случаи "обнуляем" строку), сразу добавляя ей `n - i` пробелов. *Мы должны использовать модуль, т.к. `n - i` может возвращать отрицательное число, когда `i > n`, а метод `repeat()` не принимает отрицательные числа.

   Почему `|n - i|`? Потому, что минимальное число, которое выйдет будет `|5 - 1| = 4`, 4 пробела для первой строки. А среднее `|5 - 5| = 0`, для строки, где все цифры. Ну и максимальное `|5 - 9| = 4`. Впринципе, нам подходит.
3. И последнее, мы должны добавить сами цифры в реверсе. Делаем так же, но не забываем о `n - |n - i|`. Следуя той же логике, что и выше, `min(n - |n - i|) = 5 - |5 - 1| = 1`, т.е. одна цифра в первой строке     `1` и так же с максимальным `5 - |5 - 9| = 1`, 1 цифр в последнюю строку и т.д.

---

```
int n = 5;
String str = "";

for (int i = 1; i < n * 2; i++) {
    str = " ".repeat(Math.abs(n - i));
    for (int j = n - Math.abs(n - i); j > 0; j--) str += j;
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Конечно тот ещё говонокод, но реализация через циклы приходит на ум первой

```
    //Число для отображения
    final int number = 5;
    //Кол-во пробелов
    int probel = number;

    for(int p=probel;p>0;p--){

        //Добавляем пробелы
        for(int add_probel=1;add_probel<p;add_probel++)
            System.out.print(" ");

        //Добавляем числа
        for(int i=number-(p-1);i>0;i--){
            System.out.print(""+i);
        }

        System.out.flush();
    }

    for(int p=1;p<probel;p++){

        //Добавляем пробелы
        for(int add_probel=0 ; add_probel<p ; add_probel++)
            System.out.print(" ");

        //Добавляем числа
        for(int i=number-(p);i>0;i--){
            System.out.print(""+i);
        }

        System.out.flush();
    }
```